# How do I make this jQuery Toggle function close

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm having trouble figuring out a way to get this toggle function to close.
It will open happily, but closing is a different story.

Console Error: `property 'toggle' of undefined at focusMobileSearch`

Code:

```
function focusMobileSearch() {

    $('.mobile-search').removeClass('is-focused');

    function reveal() {
            $('.search-dropdown').css({ 'visibility': 'visible', 'height': '64px' });
            $('.input-group').delay('200').queue(function (next) {
                $(this).css('visibility', 'visible');
                next();
            });
    }

    reveal().toggle();

}
```

This was my Previous Code (it had a weird issue where the first click did nothing:

```
function focusMobileSearch() {

    $('.mobile-search').removeClass('is-focused');

    function reveal() {
        $('.search-dropdown').css({ 'visibility': 'visible', 'height': '64px' }).toggle();
        $('.input-group').delay('240').queue(function (next) {
            $(this).css('visibility', 'visible');
            next();
        }).toggle();
    }

    reveal();

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to untoggle, and when?

Comment: @Taplar So the focusMobileSearch function runs when I click a search button on the main navigation. I want the first click to set visibility to visible and I want the second click to turn the visibility back to its default state of hidden.

Comment: Ok, so `toggle()` does not change the visibility property.  It changes the `display` property.  You will have to write the logic to toggle that css property yourself.  The easiest way to do this, imo, is to make a separate class that applies the visibility and toggle that class off and on, rather than setting the visibility inline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed it:

```
function focusMobileSearch() {

    $('.ef-header-alt__search').removeClass('is-focused');

    function reveal() {
        if ($('.search-dropdown').css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
            $('.search-dropdown').css({ 'visibility': 'visible', 'height': '64px' });
            $('.input-group').delay('240').queue(function (next) {
                $(this).css('visibility', 'visible');
                next();
            })
        } else {
            $('.search-dropdown').css({'visibility': 'hidden', 'height': '0px'});
            $('.input-group').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }
    }

    reveal();

}
```

Big thanks to: @Taplar for letting me know toggle doesn't effect visibility, but rather just display property.

Answer (score 0):

Use a class for the toggle.

```js
function focusMobileSearch() {
  $('.mobile-search').removeClass('is-focused');

  function reveal() {
    $('.search-dropdown').toggle('visible');
    $('.input-group').delay('240').queue(function(next) {
      $(this).toggle('visible');
      next();
    });
  }

  reveal();

}
```

```css
.visible {
  visibility: visible;
}

.search-dropdown.visible {
  height: 64px;
}
```